# Execute very long statements in TSQL using sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sp-executesql

I would like to execute dynamic SQL statements which are about 10,000 characters.

When I use sp_executesql as below:

```
DECLARE @stmt varchar(MAX)

SET @stmt = 'xxxxxxxx.................' which is about 10,000 characters

EXEC sp_executesql @stmt
```

I got the following error

```
The character string that starts with '  select t1.e_reference xxxxxxxxxxx' is too long. Maximum length is 8000.
```

As far as I know, we can use sp_executesql to execute very long statements, can't we?

I am using SQL Server 2008, Enterprise Edition, 64 bit.

How can I achieve this?  Thanks.

Comment: Try it with nvarchar(max), it takes a nvarchar parameter, so your varchar is having to be converted, slim chance that is causing the problem

Comment: I have tried it with nvarchar(MAX) as well.  But it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show more of your actual query? I can't reproduce this. In fact I can't even see that error in `sys.messages`. Are you querying a linked server?

Comment: Yes, Martin.  I am querying against Oracle Linked Server.

Comment: The linked server part is kind of important information, well done to Martin for picking up on it

Answer (score 7):

Based on your responses in the post, you are using `linked server`.
The 8000 `char` limit is not posed by sp_executesql, but by **OPENQUERY** that you are probably using in your variable @stmt .

MSDN says this of **OPENQUERY**'s arguments:

> '`query`' Is the query string executed in the linked server. The maximum
>   length of the `string` is 8 KB.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx

To bypass this, you could probably use

```
execute (@query) at oracle_linked_server
```

Answer (score 0):

MSDN says this which is a bit vague:
*"The size of the string is limited only by available database server memory. On 64-bit servers, the size of the string is limited to 2 GB, the maximum size of nvarchar(max)."*

On 64-bit servers the limit is 2GB. It is not clear what is the limit of 32-bit servers? Is it 4000, 8000, whatever memory is available, 2GB?

Answer (score 0):

Break the code up into strings of less than 4k characters, then replace single quotes with double quotes, lastly execute like below.

```html
SET @STM1 = REPLACE( @STM1, CHAR(39), CHAR(39) + CHAR(39);
SET @STM2 = REPLACE( @STM2, CHAR(39), CHAR(39) + CHAR(39); 
SET @STM3 = REPLACE( @STM3, CHAR(39), CHAR(39) + CHAR(39);
EXECUTE( N'EXECUTE sp_executesql N''' + @STM1 + N' ' + @STM2 + N' ' + @STM3 + '''' );
```

Answer (score -1):

The @stmt parameter for sp_executesql has a data type of nvarchar(8000), so you have exceeded the limit.

Either refactor your SQL statements into smaller parts, or put the SQL into a stored procedure.

Comment: based on what do you say it ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001(v=SQL.100).aspx - for a while now the docs have shown it is limited by nvarchar(max), historically back in sql 2k you would be right